# create a tuple with map, with conditional evenorodd list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

Here is my code :

```
evenorodd=[1,2,3]
list1=['a','b','c']
list2=['A','B','C']

res = tuple(map(lambda x: True if x % 2 != 0 else False, evenorodd))

print(res)
```

the output:

```
(False, True, False, True)
```

I want this : element of list1 if x%2!=0 (if element of evenorodd is odd)
              element of list2 else (if element of evenorodd is even)
The output that I look for:

```
('a','B','c')
```

and I want to do that on one line

```
res = tuple(map(lambda x: ??? if x % 2 != 0 else ???, evenorodd))
```

Thank you

Comment: we should probably use an enumerate here.

Comment: thanks, can I use enumerate without for loop? I tried that : `res = tuple(map(lambda x: enumerate(list1)if x % 2 != 0 else enumerate(list2), evenorodd)` and I obtain that : `(<enumerate object at 0x7f4074297090>, <enumerate object at 0x7f40742970d8>, <enumerate object at 0x7f4074297120>)`

Comment: Well not exactly (depends), but we could use a list comprehension here.

Comment: I also tried a for loop with conditional but I can't do the else statement

Comment: did you have a look at my answer?

Comment: If you want to store a third array you might aswell make it boolean like `[True, False, True]`. If you want to use the index I'd suggest my solution with enumerate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip`:

```
evenorodd=[1,2,3]
list1=['a','b','c']
list2=['A','B','C']
new_result = [a if c%2 == 0 else b for a, b, c in zip(list2, list1, evenorodd)]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'B', 'c']
```

Comment: @AntonvBR Not exactly. I think it is important to retain the OP's original `evenorodd` structure. For instance, What if the input is`[1,3,6,7]`, `['a','b','c','d']`, `['A','B','C','D']`?

Comment: @AntonvBR But to be fair, it is merely an assumption. I will delete my post if you think it too closely emulates yours.

Comment: It's ok. I was having a conversation with OP in comments trying to understand what he really wanted.

Comment: @bryantetris If you want to store a third array you might aswell make it boolean like [True, False, True] and use a "tripple zip" like Ajax1234 here proposes. If you want to use the index I'd suggest my solution with enumerate. In any case you might accept the one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
res = tuple([x if not ind % 2 else y for ind, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(list1,list2))])
print(res)
#('a', 'B', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `numpy.where()`:

```
import numpy as np
tuple(np.where([i%2 for i in evenorodd], list1, list2))
```

Comment: thank you everyone, but I forgot that I absolutely had to use map

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses `map` and `lambda`-function exclusively:

```
tuple(map(lambda v: v[0] if v[2] % 2 else v[1], zip(list1, list2, evenorodd)))
```